# Every Bounded set contained in a Compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, topological-vector-spaces

In a general metric space, is every bounded set contained in a compact set?

Comment: What is a bounded set in a *general* topological space?

Comment: And even if we resolve to complete metric spaces, this doesn't hold. You need total boundedness.

Comment: Yes, of course. I meant "metric", not "topological". Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean a metric space: Consider an infinite set X with the discrete metric. Show that X is bounded but not compact.